# Postman - Could not send request

Tags: .net, api, .net-core

I want to test my GET route with postman. I have a .NET project and when I right click on the project name in Solution explorer - and then select properties, I can see that its running on port 5001. (See screenshot below).

[image]

I have a controller called ProductsController. (Code below)

```
namespace DutchTreat.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[Controller]")]
    public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IDutchRepository _repository;
        private readonly ILogger<ProductsController> _logger;
        public ProductsController(IDutchRepository repository, ILogger<ProductsController> _logger)
        {

        }

        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(200)]
        [ProducesResponseType(400)]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Product>> Get()
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok(_repository.GetAllProducts());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Failed to get products: {ex}");
                return BadRequest("Failed to get products");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I visit this route in postman,  http://localhost:5001/api/products, I receive a 500 error:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5001

[image]

I wondered if you were able to tell me what the problem might be?

Thanks,

Robert

Answer (score 0):

`5001` is your `https` port; try connecting to:

```
https://localhost:5001/api/products
```